# Identify row number where preceding cell value in column differ only in visible range

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to retrieve the row number within the visible range (the data is filtered) where the current cell being checked does not equal <> the previous cell in the same column.

I wrote the following code that does return the correct row of the change between preceding and current (over/under) cells, however, in the immediate window it returns the same row value 22 times, the same number of times that I have visible rows.  I just need to return the row number once.  It must be happening in the for i loop I have.  Your help is much appreciated.

```
Sub PreceedingVisibleCellDiff()
'find row number when cell value differs from cell above

Dim LastRow As Long, cl As Range, rng As Range

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
Debug.Print "LastRow: " & LastRow

Set rng = Range("B5:B" & LastRow)

For Each cl In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    For i = LastRow To 5 Step -1

    If Cells(i, 12) <> "" Then
        If Cells(i, 8) <> Cells(i, 8).Offset(-1) Then Debug.Print i
    End If

    Next i

Next cl

End Sub
```

Comment: Loop through your `cl` range, not `i`. The reason you get repeating output is because your `For Each` loop is not really doing anything. It just repeats the `For i` loop over and over. (It will repeat equal to the number of visible cells in your `rng`

Comment: That's it!  Thanks for pointing out the obvious that I should have seen long before.

Comment: The code above has been corrected per urdearboy's advice.

Comment: As a suggestion, leave the initial question like you had it, and post the working code as an answer (you can even mark it as such). That way others will understand what the problem was and how to solve it.

Comment: @XLmatters - the community would benefit if you did make the updated suggested by Ricardo. This way, anyone who has this issue in the future can see the **problem and the solution**

Comment: I rolled back your edit. Please post the working code below as a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution based off urdearboy's recommendation above:

```
Sub PreceedingVisibleCellDiff()
'find row number when cell value differs from cell above

Dim LastRow As Long, cl As Range, rng As Range

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
Debug.Print "LastRow: " & LastRow

Set rng = Range("B5:B" & LastRow)

For Each cl In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    'check that colum L(12) has an action item
    If Cells(cl.Row, 12) <> "" Then
        'at the row in column H (8) where the preceding cell does not match, there is a
        'new action to be acted upon
        If Cells(cl.Row, 8) <> Cells(cl.Row, 8).Offset(-1) Then Debug.Print cl.Row

        '< do something here using cl.Row >

    End If

Next cl

End Sub
```